# Restore DB backup: schema node not found for object TABLE DATA

Tags: postgresql, backup, schema, pg-restore

I made a backup from my db in postgresql via pgadmin. now I want to restore it in my pesonal laptop. but I get this error for each table in my DB:

schema node not found for object TABLE DATA